# Dealing with exception output with Lambda Function

Tags: lambda, pyspark, rdd

I have the following RDD which I need to perform a division operation between the two integers in a tuple. However, some of the division operations are 0/0.

```
rdd=[('f10.txt', (0.0, 0.0)),
 ('f1.txt',
  (0.002195968354828256, 0.0672428463151798)),
 ('8.txt', (0.0, 0.0)),
 ('f3.txt',
  (0.0014248992750671376, 0.06494950445087552)),
 ('f9.txt', (0.0, 0.0))]
```

i tried this if else condition but it throws me an error:

```
rdd=rdd.map(lambda x : (x[0],x[1][0]/x[1][1] int(s) if s.isdigit() else 0)    )
```

My desired output would be:

```
rdd=[('f10.txt', 0),
     ('f1.txt',
      0.0343497),
     ('8.txt', 0),
     ('f3.txt',
      0.047558),
     ('f9.txt', 0)]
```

Comment: Are you setting the value of s somewhere earlier in your program? The if/else immediately follows your division operation, which isn't valid python so it's a bit hard to tell exactly what you want the expression to be.

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks fo the reply. Are there any common if/else statements that will convert an NA output into a zero? I am not sure how it fits in the context of a lambda function.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what your intended output is? Do you want the outputs of nonzero division to be an integer value, float value, or the word "float"? My best guess would be that you want to give the actual float value in the case of normal division, and a 0 if division by zero. Here's some code that should work:

`rdd=rdd.map(lambda x : (x[0], x[1][0]/x[1][1] if x[1][1] != 0 else 0))`

Comment: yup! that's exactly what I need! I have updated my question too!